# Get value from ng for generated inputs

Tags: angular, ngfor, ionic4

I'm doing an app with Ionic framework, so far I have inputs generated by *ngFor and I want to get the value of each input after clicking on a button. I've tried with Reactive forms but was not able to make it work.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of players; index as i">
    <ion-chip>
     <ion-input placeholder="Nombre jugador {{i+1}}"  type="text"></ion-input>
     <ion-icon name="person-add"></ion-icon>
   </ion-chip>
 </ion-item>
<br />
</ion-list>
```

and my .ts file.

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.getJugadores();
 }

getJugadores(){
  this.storage.get("num_players").then(x =>{
    if (x){
      this.players = new Array(x);
    }else{
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
}
```

I want to store each value in an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Angular, one of the easiest ways to get/set data onto a form is to simply use `[(ngModel)]` data binding.

1) Define a structure for your data. If you have multiple inputs, consider defining an array.

2) Bind to that structure using `[(ngModel)]`.

Here is some information that may help: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

**Template code**

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of players; index as i">
     <input placeholder="Nombre jugador {{i+1}}"  type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="item.name"/>
 </div>
```

**Component code**

```
  players: Player[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    // Call a service to get data
    // Hardcoded here as an example
    this.players = [
      {id: 1, name: "Joe"},
      {id:2, name: "Stefan"}
    ]
  }
```

**Interface code**

```
export interface Player {
  id: number,
  name: string
}
```

I have a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5uppm

Comment: But that means that I have the variable declared on my `ts` file, but in my case the numbers of inputs is not constant, so I cant declare those variable in order to get the value with `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: If you are using an array, the number of inputs does not have to be constant. I updated my answer with more code as an example.

Comment: Thank you for your help.